# Assigning chmod permissions and excluding a file in a Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, chmod

I am trying to write a shell script that allows a user to enter a permission, a directory name, and a file to exclude using the chmod command. I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I am very new to shell scripting, so it may be a simple syntax error. My code is shown below:

```
    #!/bin/bash

clear
echo "   ====================================
    We need our rights!
    Set file permissions!
    Only use numerical representation
    of permissions listed below!
   ====================================

        1) r. read access to a file
        2) w. write access to a file
        3) x. Execute access to a file "

echo "Please enter a permission:"
read permish
echo
echo "Please enter your directory name:"
read directory
echo
echo "Please enter a file to exclude:"
read exclFile

perm=""

if [ "$permish" -eq 1 ]; then
   "$perm" = "u+r"
elif [ "$permish" -eq 2 ]; then
   "$perm" = "u+w"
elif [ "$permish" -eq 3 ]; then
   "$perm" = "u+x"
else
    echo "invalid input"
fi

<chmod perm= "$perm" >
  <fileset dir= "$directory" >
    <exclude name= "**/$exclFile" />
  </fileset>
</chmod>

echo "Done!"
```

Stephan Ferraro's answer wasn't very helpful to me, but I solved my problem. I just went about it in a different way. This was the result:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "   ====================================
    We need our rights!
    Set file permissions!
    Only use numerical representation
    of permissions listed below!
   ====================================

        1) r. read access to a file
        2) w. write access to a file
        3) x. Execute access to a file "

echo "Please enter a permission number
 Exit with [x]:"
   read permish
 echo "Please enter a directory name:"
read dir
 echo "Please enter a file to exclude:"
read xcldfile
   case "$permish" in
1)
 chmod -R u+r $dir
 chmod u-r */$xcldfile
;;
2)
 chmod -R u+w $dir
 chmod u-w */$xcldfile
;;
3)
 chmod -R u+x $dir
 chmod u-x */$xcldfile
;;
x)
 exit;;
*)
 echo "invalid input. Try again"
 sleep 2
bash HW2P1.sh
;;
esac
 echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not a bash compliant file:
XML-tags like  have nothing to do in this script. For excluding a file, you have to create first a file list of the directory by excluding the files in this list, then apply the chmod on the non excluded files. Useful commands for this would be ls/find, grep -v, xargs -n1. Please check the man pages for more information about it.

Comment: Your solution is not complete: Excluding means to not execute "chmod" at all for the file in $xcldfile.